# Django: Check if foreign key attribute is set

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
```

This model is supposed to be the root model in some inheritance tree and content_type attribute is a kind of a hint about what type is really stored.
Obviously, I should calculate `content_type` transparently upon A instance creation. I think, in `__init__`. But there is a problem - there are two main contexts in which A instances are created:

1. `a = A(name='asdfdf') # here we must fill in content_type`
2. by `QuerySet` machinery with `*args` tuple. In this case I shouldn't fill in `content_type`

So, I'm trying to write:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.content_type is None: # << here is the problem
        self.content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self)
```

The thing is `self.content_type` is `ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor` instance with `__get__` overriden so that it throws in case value is not set. Yes, I can do following:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    try: 
        self.content_type
    except Exception, v:
        self.content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self)
```

But I don't like it. Is there a more 'polite' way to check if the `ForeignKey` attribute is set?

Comment: Firstly, if you want `content_type` to be optional, I think you'll need to set `blank = True, null = True` on your field definition.

Comment: I don't want it to be optional, I just don't want to set its value if it has already been set by Django (in the process of reading from DB).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Does it work if you examine `self.content_type_id` instead of `self.content_type`?

Comment: Certainly, you are right. It's exactly what I need. Thank you.